# Parent PID Spoofing implementation error in Rust

Tags: winapi, rust, pid, spoofing

I am currently trying to implement a simple Parent PID Spoofing in Rust but I'm facing with Segfault errors / Invalid Handle when creating process whom I'm trying to spoof its parent.

I made this code and modified it a lot in order to accomplish the wanted result:

```rust
let mut sinfo = STARTUPINFOEXA::default();

let mut cb_attribute_list_size = 0;
const PROC_THREAD_ATTRIBUTE_PARENT_PROCESS: DWORD = 0x00020000;
let mut h_parent_process: HANDLE = NULL as HANDLE;
let dw_pid: DWORD = 2176;
const CMDLINE: &str = "notepad";

unsafe {
    InitializeProcThreadAttributeList(
        null_mut(),
        1,
        0,
        &mut cb_attribute_list_size
    );

    sinfo.lpAttributeList = HeapAlloc(
        GetProcessHeap(),
        0,
        cb_attribute_list_size
    ).cast();

    if InitializeProcThreadAttributeList(
        sinfo.lpAttributeList,
        1,
        0,
        &mut cb_attribute_list_size
    ) == 0 {
        eprintln!("[x] Error Initializing proccess attribute");
        return Ok(());
    }

    h_parent_process = OpenProcess(
        PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS,
        0,
        dw_pid // explorer.exe
    );

    if h_parent_process.is_null() {
        eprintln!("[x] Error opening parent process");
        return Ok(());
    }

    if UpdateProcThreadAttribute(
        sinfo.lpAttributeList,
        0,
        0x00020000,
        transmute::<PHANDLE, LPVOID>(&mut h_parent_process),
        size_of::<HANDLE>(),
        null_mut(),
        null_mut()
    ) == 0 {
        eprintln!("[x] Error updating PROC_THREAD_ATTRIBUTE_PARENT_PROCESS");
        return Ok(());
    }

    let mut process_info= PROCESS_INFORMATION::default();
    sinfo.StartupInfo.dwFlags = STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW | STARTF_USESTDHANDLES;
    sinfo.StartupInfo.wShowWindow = 0;
    sinfo.StartupInfo.cb = size_of::<STARTUPINFOEXA>() as u32;

    if CreateProcessA(
        null_mut(),
        CMDLINE.to_string().as_ptr() as LPSTR,
        null_mut(),
        null_mut(),
        0,
        EXTENDED_STARTUPINFO_PRESENT,
        null_mut(),
        null_mut(),
        &mut sinfo.StartupInfo,
        &mut process_info
    ) == 0 {
        eprintln!("[x] Error creating process");
        return Ok(());
    }
    println!("[+] Process created: {}", process_info.dwProcessId);

    DeleteProcThreadAttributeList(sinfo.lpAttributeList);
    CloseHandle(process_info.hProcess);
    CloseHandle(process_info.hThread);
    CloseHandle(h_parent_process);
}
```

I tried allocating the pAttributeList from Rust with `Vec::with_capacity()` or from C with `HeapAlloc()`.

The *same* code works in C but I don't know what am I doing wrong in Rust. I didn't success to find an actual implementation of Parent PID Spoofing in Rust but I found some usage of `UpdateProcThreadAttributeList()` function.

The C source code I am trying to convert to Rust can be found here: https://www.ired.team/offensive-security/defense-evasion/parent-process-id-ppid-spoofing#ppid-spoofing

Thanks for help

---**EDIT**---

I reviewed the code to use Ansi version of the API, the code works fine but does not produce the result I wanted. It spawn a notepad but with no parent (System is its).

I wonder if my call to `UpdateProcThreadAttributeList()` is correct, I think I would have to pass the reference to the Handle of the Parent Process but HANDLE structure is a `*mut c_void` and LPVOID/PVOID is also a `*mut c_void`. I'm not quite sure if the problem reside in this thing.

As one of comment suggested, there is my C code that I try to convert:

```
STARTUPINFOEX sie = { sizeof(sie) };
PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;
SIZE_T cbAttributeListSize = 0;
PPROC_THREAD_ATTRIBUTE_LIST pAttributeList = nullptr;
HANDLE hParentProcess = nullptr;
DWORD dwPid = 2176;
const char* lpCommandLine = "notepad";

InitializeProcThreadAttributeList(NULL, 1, 0, &cbAttributeListSize);
pAttributeList = (PPROC_THREAD_ATTRIBUTE_LIST)HeapAlloc(GetProcessHeap(), 0, cbAttributeListSize);
if (NULL == pAttributeList)
{
    std::cout << "[x] Error allocating heap: " << GetLastError() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}

if (!InitializeProcThreadAttributeList(pAttributeList, 1, 0, &cbAttributeListSize))
{
    std::cout << "[x] Error Initializing proccess attribute: " << GetLastError() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}

hParentProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, dwPid);
if (NULL == hParentProcess)
{
    std::cout << "[x] Error opening parent process: " << GetLastError() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}

if (!UpdateProcThreadAttribute(pAttributeList, 0, PROC_THREAD_ATTRIBUTE_PARENT_PROCESS, &hParentProcess, sizeof(HANDLE), NULL, NULL))
{
    std::cout << "[x] Error updating PROC_THREAD_ATTRIBUTE_PARENT_PROCESS: " << GetLastError() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}

sie.lpAttributeList = pAttributeList;

if (!CreateProcessA(NULL, const_cast<LPSTR>(lpCommandLine), NULL, NULL, FALSE, EXTENDED_STARTUPINFO_PRESENT, NULL, NULL, &sie.StartupInfo, &pi))
{
    std::cout << "[x] Error creating process: " << GetLastError();
    return 0;
}
std::cout << "[+] Process created: " << pi.dwProcessId << std::endl;

DeleteProcThreadAttributeList(pAttributeList);
CloseHandle(pi.hProcess);
CloseHandle(pi.hThread);
CloseHandle(hParentProcess);
```

Thanks again

--**LAST EDIT**--

I finally figured out what I was making wrong !
During CreateProcessA() call it was trying to read the location pointed by the value of the Parent Process Handle but I was passing its value directly instead of its reference.

I edited the Rust code above. Thanks all I can close this issue.

Comment: I noticed you're using `STARTUPINFOEXW` and `CreateProcessW` instead of the `A` variants. Why is that?

Comment: It would also be helpful to see your C code that works, if it is different from the code in the article.

Comment: @PitaJ UTF-16 is Windows' native character encoding. Using the wide character versions of APIs and structures reduces the number of failure modes for each API call. Plus, it doesn't have the ambiguity of the narrow character versions that use a whole set of different encodings.

Comment: @PitaJ I tried with W(ide) and A(nsi) version of the API it works barely the same way. I can change to Ansi but it is not due to this.

Comment: If you wish to share your answer, don't edit it into your question. There's a dedicated answer field below.